# time complexities of algorithms

Tags: algorithm, big-o

What are the time complexities of these two algorithms? I got 3n/2 + 6 for the first one, and 3logn + 6 for the second and I'm not sure if I'm doing them right.

```
int i  = 0 ;
double evenSum = 0.0 ;
while ( i < n) {
    evenSum = evenSum + data[i] ;
    i += 2;
}
StdOut.println(evenSum);
```

and the second is similar it just multiples by  2

```
int i = 0 ;
double evenSum = 0.0 ;
while ( i < n) {
    evenSum = evenSum + data[i] ;
    i *= 2;
}
StdOut.println(evenSum);
```

and I got 3n/2 + 6 and 3log n + 6

Comment: It seems like you're doing them right. You've counted the number of basic ops essentially correctly. Usually the final result is represented using big O or big Theta notation, so the first is O(n) and the second O(log n).

Answer (score 0):

Time complexity for the first one is O(n). The second one is infinite loop. for (i = 0) * 2 => 0 and won't exit loop. In case i = 1, then its time complexity is O(log(n)).

Answer (score 0):

**Note** that for the second code, your loop will never close as i is initialized to `0`, which means `i=i*2` will be **0** each time.

Time complexity is different from the number of steps taken to execute.

- If you are asking about time complexity then for the first it will be **O(N)** as it has linear iteration i.e.
  `i=i+2`
- For the second code, assuming that you plan to correct the initialization of `i` it will be **O(log(N))** as it has exponential iteration i.e
  `i=i*2`